# Redux vs HOC in React app with auth session

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, high-order-component, next-auth

I have React app in framework Next.js (but framework is not important) with authentification implemented.

Current app is getting user session data by API call after first load (I am using `next-auth` for this). This causes that there is interval between load and session fetch which results in small interval where user see loading spinners all over app.

I want to mitigate this with implementation of SSR (Server-side-rendering) where I can hydrate initial response with session data.

This can be easily done in Next.js by `getServerProps` method in Component, but the problem is that I need to implement this method on every single page I have.

Thats why I am searching for a way to make session state global across whole app so every page (component) can access this session data.

My main question is, if I should use HOC wrapper where I will implement `getServerProps` to receive session data, or I should use Redux store and hydrate this store with by same method.

I am not exactly sure if HOCs are still widely used, or they are just deprecated now.

I do not want to implement `getInitialProps` in Next.js custom `_app.js` file because this will disable ability to have statically genererated pages and session will be available in every page. I am planning that app needs this session data only in about half of pages.

So should I go with HOC or just inplement redux store for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

Create an authentication [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that will pass auth data down to your components. As an example:

```
interface ContextProps {
  authenticated: boolean;
  handleLogin: () => void;
  handleLogout: () => void;
}

const authContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>(undefined);
```

Along with Context, create a hook that will make use of `useEffect` to determine authenticated state - could be checking cookie exists, or await call to API to check auth status. Set this as the relevant status and use this value in your provider.

```
interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: any;
}

const AuthProvider = (({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const auth = useProvideAuth();

  return <authContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</authContext.Provider>;
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(authContext);

export default AuthProvider;
```

Wrap in your `_app.js:`

```
...
<AuthProvider>
   <Component pageProps={pageProps} />
</AuthProvider>
...
```

Access in relevant pages:

```
const Page = () => {
  const { authenticated } = useAuth();

  if (!authenticated) {
    return (
      <>
        Not authenticated
      </>
    );
  }
  ...
```

Then you can consume in your relevant components

Comment: Contexts are cool, I did not know about them, but this is not really a solution to my problem because I cannot use `getServerSideProps` to retrieve session from the server inside my Context initialization.

Comment: You don't need to use `getServerSideProps` - make an API call in your hook's `useEffect`

Comment: As I said. I do not want to use API calls. They causing delay which means that I need spinners in app (on every component what is dependent on session, or on whole app)